# Excel formula to find out if Dates in 3 columns are the same?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I am using `Excel 2016` and my workbook has a table with 3 dates columns as follows:

```
Date1          Date2          Date3
2016-03-20     2016-03-20     2016-03-20
2015-05-01     2015-05-01     2015-05-04
```

All 3 columns have been formatted as '`YYYY-MM-DD`'

I want to add a new column that will check if cell A2=B2=C2
The above formula works with numbers but not with these dates. What is the `Excel` formula to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
=AND(A1=A2,A1=A3)
```

The idea is that if A1 is equal to A2 and A1 is equal to A3, then all 3 are equal.

---

If you want to show `False` for empty cells, then this check would be ok:

```
=AND(A1=A2,A1=A3,A1<>"")
```

---

`=A2=B2=C2` **does not work at all**, because `A2=B2` is evaluated to `True` or `False` and then True or False should be equal to `C2`, which would not produce the expected result.

Comment: might want to add A1<>"" to the AND.

Comment: @Jeeped - why? If all of the cells are empty it is a good idea to still get `True` as a result.

Comment: I guess that is a judgement call; since blank cells are not dates, you aren't really saying all three dates are the same.

Comment: @Jeeped - could be, I have added it.

Comment: @Vityata Thanks. Using your proposed formula, what I needed is this one: AND(A2=B2,A2=C2)